# How to solve this probability symbolically or numerically?

Tags: programming, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to calculate the following probability

$$\mathbb{P} \big(\sum_{i=1}^{m} (A_i + S_i) \le L < \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} (A_i + S_i) \big)$$

where,

$$A_i \sim \exp(\lambda), \quad S_i \sim \exp(\mu), \quad L \sim \exp(\lambda), \quad \textrm{and }\lambda \neq \mu \textrm{ are two integers.}$$

All $A_i, S_i, L$ are mutually independent. $m$ is an integer parameter.

---

I came into a messy of integrals and failed to solve them. Therefore, I am wondering whether it can be solved symbolically (or numerically).

> How to solve the above probability symbolically with Mathematica, (or numerically) *when* $\lambda, \mu, m$ are fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P} \big(\sum_{i=1}^{m} (A_i + S_i) \le L < \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} (A_i + S_i) \big) =  \frac{\mu ^m (2 \lambda +\mu )}{2^{m+1} (\lambda +\mu )^{m+1}}$$

Observing:

```
d1 = TransformedDistribution[ a + s, {a \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[λ], 
                                     s \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[μ]}]

(* HypoexponentialDistribution[{λ, μ}] *)
```

and

```
d2 = TransformedDistribution[c + d, {c \[Distributed] HypoexponentialDistribution[{λ, μ}], 
                            d \[Distributed] HypoexponentialDistribution[{λ, μ}]}]
(* HypoexponentialDistribution[{λ, μ, λ, μ}] *)
```

and taking `m=3`:

```
dleft = HypoexponentialDistribution[Flatten[Table[{λ, μ}, {3}]]];
dright = HypoexponentialDistribution[{λ, μ}];
dmiddle = ExponentialDistribution[λ];

Probability[left < middle < left + right, 
    {left \[Distributed] dleft, middle \[Distributed] dmiddle, right \[Distributed] dright}]
```

> $\frac{\mu ^3 (2 \lambda +\mu )}{16 (\lambda +\mu )^4}$

For `m=5`, we get

> $\frac{\mu ^5 (2 \lambda +\mu )}{64 (\lambda +\mu )^6}$

and for general integer `m`:

> $ \frac{\mu ^m (2 \lambda +\mu )}{2^{m+1} (\lambda +\mu )^{m+1}} $

**Update:** Identifying the general form using `FindSequenceFunction` (thanks: @xzczd)

```
FindSequenceFunction[
 Table[With[{dl = HypoexponentialDistribution[Flatten[Table[{λ, μ]}, {i}]]]}, 
   Probability[left < middle < left + right,
      {left \[Distributed] dl, middle \[Distributed] dmiddle,  right \[Distributed] dright}]], 
  {i, 2, 10}]][m-1] // PowerExpand//FullSimplify
```

gives

> $$ 2^{-m-1} (2 \lambda +\mu ) \mu ^m (\lambda +\mu )^{-m-1} $$

Comment: Great thanks. It is amazing that Mathematica can even solve it symbolically. Maybe I have to try it manually again. I will check it and accept your answer ASAP.

Comment: One more question: How did you program for the general integer $m$? The `Table` iteration does not allow me to use $m$ directly: `Iterator {m} does not have appropriate bounds`.

Comment: @hengxin, i don't know of a way to use symbolic iterators in mma; so moving to general `m` was completely manual:)

Comment: The pattern is quite clear. But how to calculate it generally?

Comment: @hengxin You can use `FindSequenceFunction`: `FindSequenceFunction[Table[(μ^m (2 λ + μ))/(2^(m + 1) (λ + μ)^(m + 1)), {m, 5}], m]`

Comment: @xzczd, great idea; `FindSequenceFunction`  does not need a long sequence as input since the pattern is quite clear.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. However, I thought that `moving to general m was completely manual` by @kguler means solving the probability by paper-and-pencil. I am not sure about this.

Comment: hengxin, @xzczd's suggestion works perfectly. Yes, in the original post, i did find the general form using visual inspection. Just posted an update.

Comment: BTW, how to paste the inputs/outputs in *Mathematica* into this site so that it shows, say, $\lambda$ instead of its literal `\[Lambda]`?